# Can't retrieve data from table php

Tags: php, html, database, postgresql

I have created a button on my HTML page that is supposed to retrieve data from my table. However, when I click on it, no Data seems to be showing. Here is my table (artists):

```
      name      | Style |  
----------+-------------+
 Micheal Jackson | Pop
 Tyga            | Rap
 Drake           | Rap    
 50 cent         | Rap    
 King Von        | Rap
```

I am trying to print the name column but does not seem to be working? It shows a blank page. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Artists Table</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="Author" content="Ron Mercer">
   
</head>
<body>
<h1>Players Table</h1>
<h2>

<?php


$con=pg_connect("dbname=ron") or die( pg_last_error());
$name=$_GET['name'];
$res = pg_query_params("select name from artists where name= $1",array($name))
 or die( pg_last_error());
   
 while ($row = pg_fetch_row($res))
   {  
    print($row[0]."<br>");
   }

?>
</body>
```

I know that there is a good connection to my database because when I spell type my table name(artists) wrong it says:

> ERROR: relation "artisgsts" does not exist LINE 1: select name from artisgsts where name= $1 ^.

So it recognises my table, but why doesn't it print anything? Thanks.

Comment: It's not in the code you posted, but the error message says you misspelled the table name `artisgsts`

Comment: There's an extra `sg` in the name.

Comment: @Barmar That was a deliberate misspelling to verify that the connection is good. The OP explains that in the question

Comment: How are you calling the page? It needs a URL query parameter with the artist name, e.g. `scriptname.php?name=Tyga`

Comment: @Barmar The page name is artist.php. It outputs Tyga when I put: `artist.php?name=Tyga`. But what should I do if I wanna output the entire table? I tried to enter `artist.php?name=Bob`.Bob is not in my table and it doesn't print it which is a good sign.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular any ideas?

Comment: You need to look for a value in `$_GET['name']`, and if there isn't one run a query that doesn't have a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query depending on whether the URL parameter is provided.

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $condition = 'WHERE name = $';
    $params = array($_GET['name']);
} else {
    $condition = '';
    $params = array();
}

$res = pg_query_params("select name from artists $condition",$params)
    or die( pg_last_error());
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($res))
{  
    print($row[0]."<br>");
}
```